# get variable from url?

Tags: url-rewriting, filters, urls, variables

say i've got a url http://bfami.modernactivity.co.uk/category/museum/orderby/date/order/desc/

that works with;

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'category/(.+?)/orderby/([^/]+)/order/([^/]+)(/page/?([0-9]{1,}))?/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[5]&orderby=$matches[2]&order=$matches[3]', 'top' );
```

how do i get the value of orderby or order on a page? Think wordpress removes the GET values which is what i'd normally use...

Just want to highlight the active order filter on the page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up with;

```
class="<?=( strpos(  $oby ,'date' ) ? 'active' : null )?>"
```

though can imagine i'll need to get this working on one job or the other...

thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [get_query_var()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) function:

```
$orderby = get_query_var('orderby');
```

Comment: ah - this nearly works but returns 'wp_posts.post_date DESC'.

Answer (score 0):

think its: $wp_query->query_vars['orderby'].

You can dump all the query string variables by var_dump($wp_query->query_vars); It should be in there.

Comment: that also gets 'wp_posts.post_date DESC' instead of just 'date'. The original isn't in the var_dump either.

Comment: did you add orderby to the list of possible query vars with add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );?